# Xcode 5.1.1 cannot run on device with iOS 8.0 version

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode, ios

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 as I require an app which supports iOS 6.1 and Above with base SDK iOS 7.1. I tried upgrading Xcode 6.0 but it is not able to run iOS 6.1 simulators. So I reverted back to Xcode 5.1.1 with a backup that i had kept.
As I upgraded my device to iOS 8.0, I am not able to run the same on the device with Xcode 5.1.1.

The following is the screen shot of what I See in the organiser.

[image]

**Is there any way to run my app on iOS 8.0 Device using Xcode 5.1.1?**

Comment: What makes you think iOS8 can run on a older version of XCode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to gather symbols from device before connecting it to Xcode 5. Download and install Xcode 6 side by side with older Xcode. Connect iOS8 device to Xcode 6. Wait for it to collect symbols and see if device is ready for development. From now on Xcode 5 is able to "see" the device properly.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Thats really a nice way to do it.

Comment: Most links to Xcode 6 take you to the Mac App Store but you can download directly from Apple here and get a .dmg file to install yourself.
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#

Answer (score 0):

AppCode connected to xCode 5.1.1 is capable of running apps on iOS 8.